# Objective C Storyboard Why the ParentViewController is nil

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

I'm using storyboard created a navigation app, my question is when push view2 from view1 by using segue, why view2.parentViewController is nil? but not the ViewController of view1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `parentViewController` is not the view controller which pushed the current view controller onto the navigation stack.

What the `parentViewController` is, can be seen in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/parentViewController).